# item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '94'

Tags: tridion, tridion-content-delivery

I have installed DXA 1.7 (.Net) on SDL Web 8.5. Now when requesting the homepage I get the following error:

> 2017-06-21 14:09:03,216 [28] WARN  - HTML design is not published nor does file 'D:\Tridion\Sites\DXA\system\assets\version.json' exist on disk. Setting version to v0.0
>
> 2017-06-21 14:09:03,268 [28] ERROR - Item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '94'
> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '94'

I have checked the following:

1. Unpublished and republished 'Publication Settings'
2. JSON files are **not** present in `BINARYVARIANTS` Table
3. Publication Settings are published successfully to the Content Delivery Server (Deployer package contains JSON files)
4. In the Tridion GUI I can preview Publication Settings (JSON files are generated)

It looks like that after or during deploying the JSON files are disappearing and never ending up in the Broker database. Can it be that the deploying process (which is also using JSON in SDL Web 8.5) is interfering with deploying JSON files?

#### EDIT 22-06-17

I changed the Deployer to publish to the file system. Also here the files are disappearing. I also inspected the transport package. I noticed that the config folder is present in the zip file  but not anymore in the transaction folder.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the latest CD_8.5.0.3922 hotfix has resolved the issue.

Caused by an issue internally at SDL where the latest copy of the hotfix from development had not been moved to the FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I traced the issue back to the installation of hotfix CD 8.5.0.3922 which is causing issues when deploying DXA specific content.